# Salesforce - Hiding visualforce form items based on organization

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have a custom viusalforce page as part of a package that i'm developing. The package will be installed on a number of different Salesforce organizations. I require to hide certain parts of the visualforce page (input boxes) based on the organization using the package. What is the best way to accomplish this? I can hardcode it based on Organization ID but I'm not convinced this is the best way, as when clients refresh sandboxes the ID will change.

Comment: Based on what organisation criteria do you need to hide these things ?

Comment: Based on business requirements, if the client is availble to see the fields or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **rendered** attribute on `apex:input` evaluating the org criterial:

```
<apex:input ... rendered="{!facility.Facility_Address_2__c!=''||render}" ...>
```

Where `facility.Facility_Address_2__c` could be the inline evaluation criteria of some org object.field value or `render` could be a flag set on controller evaluating a deeper criteria.

Comment: That sounds great - So I have access to the orgs address field for example? Through facility?

Comment: In the visualforce page you have access to any object you define on your controller. take a look of this sample> http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/get-the-Org-Wide-Address-ID/td-p/260145